# Run custom executor in NX

Tags: node.js, eslint, nrwl-nx

I have a little request - could someone help me to integrate [XO](https://github.com/xojs/xo) into NX executor? I need this in my project instead of plain eslint. Just plain execute command, no options, fancy features, just run and forget. Please help

Simple command in executor like:

```
const {stdout, stderr} = execSync(
  'xo index.ts',
);
```

Throws

```
Error: Command failed: xo index.ts
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:871:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:943:15)
    at /Users/me/workspace/my-app/libs/xo/src/executors/echo/executor.ts:20:35
```

Comment: Maybe you should pass the node_modules path to `execSync` or just import xo in your executor and use it directly instead of calling it from `execSync`.